# multer onFileUploadData is not executed

Tags: node.js, express, upload, event-handling, multer

The following code uploads the file correctly, but the onFileUploadData is never hit. I have tried examples with older multer where it seems to work, but not with this latest version. Any ideas?

```
//Server.js
var express =   require("express");
var multer  =   require('multer');
var app         =   express();

app.use(multer({
  dest: './uploads/',
  onFileUploadData:function(file, data, res, req){
      console.log('onFileUploadData');
  }
}).single('userPhoto'));



 app.get('/',function(req,res){
       res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});

 app.post('/api/photo',function(req,res){

     console.log('ended');
     res.end("ended");

});

 app.listen(3000,function(){
     console.log("Working on port 3000");
});
```

In the package.json file:

```
{
   "name": "file_upload",
   "version": "0.0.1",
   "dependencies": {
     "express": "4.13.4",
     "multer": "1.1.0"
   }
}
```

In the view file:
    //index.html

```
<html>

<form id        =  "uploadForm"
      enctype   =  "multipart/form-data"
      action    =  "/api/photo"
      method    =  "post"
>
<input type="file" name="userPhoto" accept="application/x-zip-compressed,image/*"> 
<input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>


</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The eventhandlers have been removed from Multer.